# how to maintain different versions of a symfony web site

Tags: php, git, symfony, versioning

I'm working on a symfony 2 web site, it is a product our company sells (every client gets his own installation).

Each of our client gets a slightly different version of the site: sometimes the differences are small (different strings, slightly different templates), and sometimes they are bigger (different bundles activated, different database schema, different security.yml file etc.)

Currently each version sits on its own git branch. This works for now as we only started selling and don't have many clients(=branches) yet.

But I want to move to a better solution.
Any ideas?

Thanks,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree. If it's a single application, then branches per client or release, ie configurations that need separate histories (change tracking), are precisely the correct practice. Clients use/share the same app, "core", whatever, but possibly you want to control when changes in one client's features/bugs are merged into the other configurations, ie branches. Each client will have to be "upgraded" by merging from the development branch to client's branch, separately, manually. You want to pay this overhead to gain stability and isolation.

As for the specific differences you mentioned:

- Different strings: client specific configs, constants, deployment stuff, should probably be in a per-client/deployment module (include file, whatever), that you can simply ignore when merging, so that the core app code will have no client/deployment specific differences, ever.
- Slightly different templates: meh, this smells bad; if you can use symbolic constants or partials or whatever, and move the differences to a config.php, then see the above solution. Otherwise, don't template diffs suggest it's not the same app anymore?
- Different bundles activated: if you can put the include statements in the config.php, no problem.
- Different database schema: nasty business. Can this app be made schema-independent? Can you do polymorphism somehow? Nu, I don't know, haven't touched PHP in twenty years, I only do CoffeeScript and NoSQL now. ;o)
- Different security.yml: same as with config.php, not a problem, just don't merge that file, or even stop tracking it (remove from repo) altogether.

HTH.
 ;o)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that a branch is a good solution as its not intended for this kind of use case. As i see it, branches should be used for a staging or features/fixes.

As i see it, you have few options (in case you are not familiar with those options, you should read more about them in the links i attached):

- **Git submodule**. "A submodule allows you to keep another Git repository in a subdirectory of your repository. The other repository has its own history, which does not interfere with the history of the current repository. This can be used to have external dependencies such as third party libraries for example." http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule
- **Composer**. This is what i think would best suite you. Use a regular dependencies manager (composer for php, npm for nodejs etc..). I will give you full control over the version been used + easy deployment options. https://getcomposer.org/

Another option would to do it "old school".. In case they are all in the same server, just keep the "Core" stuff in the root folder and include it for each project. It's no a recommended way to go but it might be enough and won't require much changes from you

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was very informative, but I don;t think I can modulerize it enough to solve my problem with composer.

The git submodule thing is new to me, and looks very useful. thanks!